# Using jQuery to select multiple divs which contain X AND Y

Tags: jquery, contains

I want to find products which contain a set of different classes and then remove it. Using preferably only jQuery.

So far I have tried multiple variations of:

```
$('.div1:contains(\"Cat\"), .div2:contains(\"dog\")').remove();
$('.div1:contains(\"Cat\").div2:contains(\"dog\")').remove();
$('.div1:contains(\"Cat\"):contains(\"dog\")').remove();
```

The only variation that works is this:

```
$('.div1:contains(\"cat\"), .div1:contains(\"dog\")').remove();
```

..which doesnt quite answer to my problem as it removes things that should be kept.

Is it possible to select two divs that contain certain words in one string of jQuery?

**Example:**

So all divs in question have the same class. All of them contain divs that have the same class. I need to identify those elements that contain classes 'cat' and 'dog' to be able to remove only them. Excluding 'giraffe' is not possible.

DIV SAMECLASS
- div1 cat
- div2 dog

DIV SAMECLASS
- div1 cat
- div2 dog

DIV SAMECLASS
- div1 cat
- div2 giraffe

Comment: It would help us answer the question if we could see the HTML you start with, and also the output you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the class of the product to the div you want to remove and then

```
$('.dog').remove();
```

you can use `data-product` as a class and then use the .attr() to find it and remove.
 If you want you can use empty(), wich wont remove the element but will remove everything inside it.

**EDIT**

After your edit example, and if i understand it you can simply use

```
if (!$('.dog').hasClass('girafe')) {//whatever you want to do with it......};
```

It verify if the element with the class 'dog' has or not the class 'girafe' and if not it will execute your code.

Comment: Unfortunately all these elements on the page are named the same, so assigning a class is not possible as it has the same problem as listed. Ill try to add an example to the description.

Comment: Add some html so we can see it. Where do you get your data? php? or its static? If its php you can add the data-id or whatever you want to call it, and then get it by the attr() and delete it or empty it. But add some html so we can help